# hibernate issues with composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing some issues with Hibernate. We need to save an object with its children. Each child has a composite primary key. One property of the key will be inserted by a trigger. Another property will be set from the program before calling `saveOrUpdate(Object)`.

But we are not able to save the object. Hibernate throws the exception `Same identifier is already exists in the session`.

I have tried `session.clear()`, but I get the same exception. When I tried `session.merge()`, only the last child was saved, others were ignored.

Comment: can you publish the hbm files or java of the object you are trying to save.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going to need in the same Hibernate Session the objects once saved, you could detach them right after saving with [`Session.evict()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
// children is the collection of detached children, ready to save
for (Child child : children){
    session.save(child);
    session.evict(child);
}
```

Alternatively, this entry in the Hibernate Forums might be helpful: [Before Insert Trigger and ID generator](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2440674). There's an implementation of an [`AbstractPostInsertGenerator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/AbstractPostInsertGenerator.html) you can integrate to suit your needs.